# Normalized State with Partial and Complete Resource Loading

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization

I am trying to normalize my state and can't quite figure out how to handle partial & complete resources, namely whether should they share the same slice of state or be relegated to their own slices.

A little more info:

When I make a request for a list of `things`, the server responds with a list of partials.

```
[ { id: 1, name: "thing1"},
  { id: 2, name: "thing2"},
  ...
  { id: N, name: "thingN"} ]
```

When I make a request for a single `thing`, the server responds with a more complete object.

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  name: "thing1",
  img_url: "url1",
  description: "description1",
  ... and more fields
}
```

Both the partial list and detailed information need to be present at the same time.

So should these partial and complete `things` all be in the same slice of state?

If so what is a best practice for managing whether a given `thing` has been partially or completely fetched?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the purpose of fetching a single item? Probably showing it? Why not set up your state like:

```
this.state = {
  allThings: [],
  singleThing: {}
};
```

And fill it up accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can go about this a few ways:

1. Have an incomplete object like so:

   ```
   {
     id: 1,
     name: 'thing1',
     detail: null //this would be a JS object when populated
   }
   ```

   How you would use this: in a component that uses the detail view, you check for null on the state. This means that you can lazy load details if you will need multiple in the future, as well as not have to retrieve them again if needed. However, this isn't great if information needs to be updated (you would have to resolve both null and the last retrieve date, can be risky for creating stale data).
2. Manage the two as completely different nodes on your state, where the detail view is either an array or just a singular object. This approach would work better if you want to be always updating the object on a lifecycle event (e.g. on a component mount you always want to refresh the data).

My personal preference is #1 - I use Firebase a lot and this works really well as the real time DB handles when the data should be updated, and then having them in the state means I can display data super fast to the user if it's pre-loaded.